# Missing the ‘maven package’ menu entry in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm using Eclipse 3.7 with m2eclipse. Previously I know there was a menu entry ‘maven package’ but since I reinstalled Ubuntu there is no entry and I have to ‘maven install’ to do the same.

Now I'm wondering if it is possible to get the ‘maven package’ back so I could test something without installing it and allow other projects to use the test version as dependency.

Answer (score 25):

Just use `Maven Build...` and type `package` in the goal field.

Comment: And how could I add this to the menu without define this for each project?

Comment: For all reading this: the solution of @akcasoy actually gives a fuller answer.

Comment: this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 9):

I also recently wanted to have this option with the new version of m2eclipse. The best solution i could find is, to create a configuration with the goal package, and as base directory give a variable name ${selected_resource_loc}. Still you have to go to run configurations page, but at least you don't have to define a new configuration for each project, but use the predefined one.

- right-click project
- run as
- run configurations..
- double click maven build (to create a new configuration)
- give a name for configuration e.g. package
- click variables
- select "selected_resource_loc" and click ok
- write your goal e.g. "package" or "clean package"
- run

The next time when you want to package another project, you can use this configuration again:

- right-click project
- run as
- run configurations..
- select your maven configuration
- run

At least you will not have to create a new configuration each time you want to package, as with maven build...

Comment: I'm not sure what the outcome of the step 'select "selected_resource_loc"' should have been.  I had 'base directory' pre-filled with my project path.  Just keeping that and doin the rest of the steps here worked for me.