# add new maven run configuration to menu in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

Is there some way to add to the existing maven configurations in the "run configuration menu", available in "Run -> Run as" in Eclipse?
I'd like to add my commonly used goals, like "integration-test", to the existing ones, like "maven build" etc.

I used the variable "${project_loc}" for base directory, but how can I place the new configuration in the maven run configuration menu? I don't see the option in the preferences or anywhere.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Short answer is you can't. Eclipse generally encouraging to not clutter context menus.

However when using [m2eclipse](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) you can use `Run As... / Maven Build...` menu to create launch configurations for your Maven builds. After that you can use `Run As... / Maven Build` (or Alt-Shift-X, M shortcut) to invoke previously created configurations, so if there is more then one been created you'll see a selection dialog.

Comment: This way creates a new run configuration for each project that this command is used for. You should modify one configuration with this "${project_loc}" and use this one.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple plugin project that fills this need: [Eclipse Custom Maven Presets Plugin](https://github.com/albertus82/eclipse-custom-maven-presets-plugin):

[image: The Run As menu with a new item]

You can see a new `Maven clean package` item with a blue icon, but according to the doc it's possible to add up to 9 custom items.